# Text getting out of span tag

Tags: css, x-editable

I have a span tag. Inside Table's td element. I am using x-editable component to form the grid. As you can see in the attached image, the text "OB1 Charity License1" is going out of the tag. Any help on that?
[image]

Posting the entire div tag from HTML:

```html
<div collapse="pnlRuleBasicInformation" class="panel-wrapper" >
                <div class="panel-body" id="conditionTable" style="height:200px;overflow: auto;">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover bg-white">
                        <tr style="font-weight: bold">
                            <td style="width:5%">Association</td>
                            <td style="width:10%">Condition Type</td>
                            <td style="width:70%" colspan="2">Condition</td>
                            <td style="width:5%">Soft/Hard</td>
                            <td style="width:5%">Active</td>
                            <td style="width:5%">Edit</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr ng-repeat="condition in RuleCreator.Conditions">
                            <td>
                                <div ng-show="condition.showAssociation">
                                    <span editable-select="condition.association" class="form-control" e-name="association" e-form="rowform"
                                          e-ng-options="s.id as s.name for s in RuleCreator.Association">{{ RuleCreator.showAssociationName(condition) }}</span>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <!-- Personal, Educational -->
                                <span editable-select="condition.ConditionType" class="form-control" e-name="SelectedCondition" e-form="rowform"
                                      e-ng-change="RuleCreator.ConditionTypeChange($data,condition.id)"
                                      e-ng-options="s.id as s.name for s in RuleCreator.ConditionType">{{ RuleCreator.showConditionType(condition) }}</span>
                            </td>
                            <td style ="width:10%">
                                <div class="col-lg-1" ng-show="condition.IsConditionTypeSelected">
                                    <span editable-select="condition.conditionOption" class="form-control" e-name="conditionOption" e-form="rowform"
                                          e-ng-change="RuleCreator.ConditionChange($data,condition.id)"
                                          e-ng-options="ddlConditionOptions.id as ddlConditionOptions.name for ddlConditionOptions in RuleCreator.Condition">{{ RuleCreator.showCondition(condition) }}</span>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td><!-- Age -->
                                <div class="col-lg-8" ng-show="condition.IsConditionSelected">
                                    <table>
                                        <tr>
                                            <!-- is greator than, etc -->
                                            <td style="padding-right:10px" ng-repeat="c in condition.AvailableControls">
                                                <!--<span ng-if="c.ControlType == 'DropDown' || c.ControlType == 'Textbox'">{{c.type}}</span>-->
                                                <span style="display:block" ng-if="c.ControlType == 'DropDown'" e-name="optionId_{{c.id}}" class="form-control"
                                                      editable-select="condition.optionId_{{c.id}}" e-form="rowform"
                                                      e-ng-change="RuleCreator.setDependentControl($data,condition.id, c.id)"
                                                      e-ng-options="ddlOptions.id as ddlOptions.name for ddlOptions in c.Options">{{ RuleCreator.showOptionName(condition,c.id) }}</span>
                                                <span ng-if="c.ControlType=='Textbox'" editable-text="condition.valueEntered" e-name="valueEntered"
                                                      e-form="rowform">{{ condition.valueEntered || &apos;empty&apos; }}</span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span editable-select="condition.stopOption" class="form-control" e-name="stopOption" e-form="rowform"
                                      e-ng-options="ddlstopOptions.id as ddlstopOptions.name for ddlstopOptions in RuleCreator.StopOption">{{ RuleCreator.showStopOption(condition) }}</span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span editable-checkbox="condition.IsActive" class="form-control" e-form="rowform" e-name="IsActive">{{(condition.IsActive==true?'Yes':'No')}}</span>
                            </td>
                            <td style="white-space: nowrap">
                                <!-- form-->
                                <form editable-form="" name="rowform" onbeforesave="RuleCreator.saveCondition($data, condition.id)" 
                                      ng-show="rowform.$visible" shown="RuleCreator.inserted == condition" class="form-buttons form-inline">
                                    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="rowform.$waiting" title="Save" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">
                                        <em class="fa fa-save"></em>
                                    </button>
                                    <button type="button" ng-disabled="rowform.$waiting" ng-click="rowform.$cancel();RuleCreator.ConditionAddEditMode = false;" title="Cancel"
                                            class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
                                        <em class="fa fa-times"></em>
                                    </button>
                                </form>
                                <div ng-show="!rowform.$visible" class="buttons">
                                    <button ng-click="rowform.$show();RuleCreator.ConditionAddEditMode = true;" title="Edit" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">
                                        <em class="fa fa-pencil"></em>
                                    </button>
                                    <button ng-click="RuleCreator.removeCondition($index)" title="Delete" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
                                        <em class="fa fa-trash"></em>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: What is the specific effect that you want to achieve that is not being achieved now?

Comment: The text "OB1 Charity  License1" should be accomodated as "Charity"(second from left). Currently, it is going out of the box (span).

Comment: Accommodated how? Should the box expand to fit the text or should the text be clipped by the box. How does the layout respond to the change in size of the box in the former scenario? Do the boxes break onto a second line when they are too wide to fit into the viewport? This question needs many more details and your actual CSS to get a useful answer.

Comment: Actually there is very less CSS applied here as it is straight from the x-editable tool. However, I need to add my own styling to achieve my desired output. Further, the box should expand to fit the text.

Comment: the enter div tag has been added

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this. The real culprit was "class="form-control" in HTML. After removing the same, I was able to get the desired result, as there is no boxes shown. Please note that this css class is not created by me, it is provided by AngulaJS library.